# Best way of storing text for MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm developing a board that allows people to list and search for Minecraft servers (that people have submitted).

I'd like to give people the ability to submit a short, 300 word description about their server when submitting it, however, I'm unsure what the best way to do it would be.

I was thinking of having a separate table from my main table purely for storing this information as TEXT. The information about the server would be retrieved from the table via GET method.

Is this all sound? Is there a better way to store a somewhat small amount of text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `TEXT` as your datatype for a new col in your *servers table (no need for a new table, unless this data has a relationship with other tables).
2. Use prepared query's when inserting into your database.
3. Use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when displaying back to your users.

Optional strip all html and allow limited bbcode or markdown

Answer (score 3):

Store it in a field right along with the rest of the server info. Use a `TEXT` column type

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a separate table to store description and then have a unnecessary table join to retrieve records. Instead have description in the same table and give it a datatype as TEXT

Comment: I heard that retrieving TEXT from MySQL tables takes a little bit longer, so I was unsure if it was a good idea to put it in the same table.

Comment: I have always preferred using same table over joining two tables for this small data. Go ahead it is not a problem

Comment: @CaseyWeed, If you don't want to retrieve the TEXT column, then don't include that column name in the list of columns in your select-list, and don't use `SELECT *` (which is a good thing to avoid anyway).